# Voltage divider rule

Tags: circuit-analysis

Consider the following circuit :

[image]

If we need to find the voltage drop across R2 , this will be V2=(R2/R1+R2) *(-12). My question is why we have negative sign in the formula here ?

Comment: This formula does not look correct. I think you forgot parentheses somewhere (two pairs of them).

Comment: @EugeneSh., Edited.

Comment: Still not right. R1+R2 should be parenthesized too. Anyway, the minus is to indicate the polarity relative to the chosen reference. But your circuit does not indicate the reference, so it can be either way.

Comment: Voltage has a polarity, but it is relative. If you say for your circuit that every voltage that has its negative before it's positive in the clockwise direction, then the power supply will be negative, but the drops on the resistors will be positive. And vice versa

Comment: Wouldn't a *negative drop* in voltage not just be a *raise* in voltage?

Comment: @Huisman Well a "voltage drop" is a name of a measured/calculated quantity, which can be both negative and positive. You usually don't change the name of the quantity based on the sign of it. You can do in the casual talk, but in mathematics you will then have to change the sign as well, and it will break your calculations.

Comment: voltage drop across R2 is always positive because it is the magnitude of the voltage drop ..... the actual voltage at the R1/R2 node can be a positive or negative value, dependent on the location of the reference point in the circuit

Answer (score 1):

The voltage will be 6V across both the resistors. It is the sign convention we follow.
[image]

The current direction in your case defines the polarity of the voltage across the resistor. It is normal to draw the supply with negative side of it towards ground (indicating lower potential).

If you imagine a multimeter being used, it all simply depends on where you are placing the positive probe and negative probe.